# Creating A Checkbox In Select List with AngularJS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am looking for a multi select checkbox solution similiar to this one: http://blog.cbolson.com/mooselect-select-list-2-sliding-checkbox-list/

I am NOT looking for something n JQuery, so please no JQuery answers. Dos this already exist in AngularJS or raw Javascript or what is some guidance on how to make something like this?

Answer (score 3):

it's just custom component that you can create yourself, nothing complex. it's more about html-markup, but not javascript.

For example AngularJS solution:

```
<div ng-controller="main">
    <div ng-click="toggle()"> {{count}} options selected</div>  
<div ng-show="showOptions">
    <label ng-repeat="option in options">{{option}}<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[$index]" ng-change="update()"/><br/></label>
  </div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/STEVER/mhb2p/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use some libraries for this. This is [dropdown-check-list](https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/) one which you can use.

You can also find the [test cases here](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/ddcl-tests.html).